# Map unavailable Networkdrive

Tags: network-shares, network-drive, windows-server-2012-r2

My HyperV-Host should connect to the shares provided by a virtual file server. Whenever I login to "early", the drives are not mapped, because the file-server-vm has not yet started.

The command I'm using in the logon script looks simple like this:

```
  net use s: \\file1.mydomain.local\share1 /PERSISTENT:NO
```

In this scenario, the share is not available on the network, so it is not mapped. Can I "force" a network drive mapping, even if the share is not (yet) available?

I could go with a persistent mapping ofc, but the shares change over time and I dont want to reconfigure each and every server, whenever a share becomes available.

is there something like a "force" option, or is it possible to distribute persistent network-drive-mappings via GPO?

Comment: You can't map a drive to a resource that doesn't exist; and when the server is down, that resource (the shared folder) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You could use group policy preferences to map the drive, rather than a script. Group policy updates every 90mins (I think) by default so your drive should map...

or, you could group policy a scheduled task to check the drive is mapped and if not map it. Probably the easiest to implement with a small script.

Comment: Just checked on the GPO. Mapping is possible, but shows the same behaviour: Drive unavailable? -> Not Mapped. I think, that frequent checks if the share is available are possible - but not the best idea to start with. But Maybe the GPO along with a persistent share might work - worst case i have to wait {GPO_UPDATE_TIME} until persistent shares are created.

Comment: You need to do a regular check. Not too frequently or you will needlessly bog down the system. A scheduled task every 15-30-60 mins suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea of @Big Chris I did it the following way:

Created the Network-Share using a GPO Object with Reconnect and "Create" Action.
(See here: http://www.howtogeek.com/99403/it-how-to-map-network-drives-on-windows-clients-via-group-policy/)

- The Clients will now connect to any "new" networkshare, once the GPO is updated.
- Due to the Reconnect Option they will not loose track of the share, even if it is not available while the client reboots.
- If i permanently delete a network share, I will add a unmap command to the logon script until it is save to assume, that all clients have disconnected.
- If i change a network share, I will modify the logon scriot to check if the volume name matches the "old" share in case I reuse that drive letter for a new share. Then I'll disconnect and let the GPO apply the new share.

The last 2 points are a bit of a workaround - but any other option than "create" will cause unmapped drives again, if they are temporary unavailable. (There is no way to decide whether a share is permantent or temporary unavailable ofc.)

Why I have choosen this solution over frequently checking for availability? Simple because with this option i can *see*, that a drive is mapped but not available - with the pulling-option i wouldn't know whether it's unavailable - or a simple error occured during mapping.